# Prediction on Employee In Time Using Previous data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I am new in Machine Learning and Deep Learning.

I am working on one use-case if any one can help pls.

We have employee attendance dataset i want to predict the employee in Time for the future days.

What algorithm i can use that will best fit to my problem. need some guidance how i can proceed.

Answer (score 0):

this is basic machine learning, if you looked it up just a bit, you would have found a solution, with that being said, you could use linear regression